# Error with numerical summation - how to specify "n choose r"?

Tags: warning-messages, summation, numerical-value

I'm trying to do the following sum:

```
NSum[((50000 - x) choose x)*(1/3^15)^x*((3^15 - x)/3^15)^(50000 - x), {x, 1, 4}]
```

But I keep getting an error saying:

```
"Summand (or its derivative) ((50000-x)\ choose\ x)\ (1/3^15)^x\ \((3^15-x)/3^15)^(50000-x) is not numerical at point x = 1."
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what's `choose`?

Comment: @Verbeia Isn't `n choose r` `C(n, r)`?

Comment: Not in Mathematica syntax, it isn't. I think you need `Binomial`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely hitting this problem because `choose` is not defined to be a numerical quantity. `NSum` requires a summation where each part evaluates to something numerical, not algebraic. Deleting the `choose` gives a result:

```
In[1]:= NSum[((50000 - x)  x)*(1/3^15)^
   x*((3^15 - x)/3^15)^(50000 - x), {x, 1, 4}]

Out[1]= 0.0034724
```

**EDIT**

Based on the additional information you have provided, you might be looking for `Binomial`.

```
NSum[Binomial[(50000 - x) , x]*(1/3^15)^x*((3^15 - x)/3^15)^(50000 - x), {x, 1, 4}]

(* 0.00347843 *)
```